# AWS SDK file upload to S3 via Node/Express using stream PassThrough - file is always corrupt

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

It's pretty straightforward. Using this code, any image file that is uploaded, is corrupt and cannot be opened. PDFs seem fine, but I noticed it's injecting values into text-based files. It's the correct file size in s3, not zero like something went wrong. I'm not sure if it's a problem w/ Express, the SDK, or a combination of both? Is it Postman? I built something similar in a work project in March of this year, and it worked flawlessly. I no longer have access to that code to compare.

No errors, no indication of any problems.

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const stream = require("stream");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "superSecretAccessKey";
const BUCKET_NAME = "my-bucket";
const BUCKET_REGION = "us-east-1";

const s3 = new aws.S3({
    region: BUCKET_REGION,
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});

const uploadStream = key => {
    let streamPass = new stream.PassThrough();
    let params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: key,
        Body: streamPass
    };
    let streamPromise = s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("ERROR: uploadStream:", err);
        } else {
            console.log("INFO: uploadStream:", data);
        }
    }).promise();
    return {
        streamPass: streamPass,
        streamPromise: streamPromise
    };
};

router.post("/upload", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let key = req.query.file_name;
        let { streamPass, streamPromise } = uploadStream(key);
        req.pipe(streamPass);
        await streamPromise;
        res.status(200).send({ result: "Success!" });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send({ result: "Fail!" });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "expresss3streampass",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.812.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

After further testing, I noticed plain-text files are being changed by Postman. For example, this source file:

```
{
    "question_id": null,
    "position_type_id": 1,
    "question_category_id": 1,
    "position_level_id": 1,
    "question": "Do you test your code before calling it \"done\"?",
    "answer": "Candidate should respond that they at least happy path test every feature and bug fix they write.",
    "active": 1
}
```

...looks like this after it lands in the bucket:

```
----------------------------472518836063077482836177
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="question.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "question_id": null,
    "position_type_id": 1,
    "question_category_id": 1,
    "position_level_id": 1,
    "question": "Do you test your code before calling it \"done\"?",
    "answer": "Candidate should respond that they at least happy path test every feature and bug fix they write.",
    "active": 1
}
----------------------------472518836063077482836177--
```

I have to think this is the problem. Postman is the only thing that changed in this equation, from when this code first worked for me. My request headers look like this:

[image]

I was the one who had originally added the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header. If I use that now, I end up with a file that has 0 bytes, in the bucket.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use multer?

Comment: @relief.melone Yes - this is streaming files rather than blowing out the container with a file that might be too large, or locking the thread on a large upload.

Comment: u can utilize streams with multer as well instead of uploading it to the container first. I am not sure but I'd be pretty confident that multer-s3-storage does just that and I do it as well in the storage engine i wrote for multer https://gitlab.com/relief-melone/multer-s3-sharp-resizer. However I am still not sure what's causing the problems with your code as my approach is pretty much the same as yours (and I'm using Postman to test too). I will still take a closer look at this as soon as I get the time. I understand that you not only want to make it work but understand what's going wrong.

Comment: is the goal of your server is only to pick a file from a user and put it on an S3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) is the way to go.

It provides a few different modes, but as far as I could tell, you have to write a custom [storage handler](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/StorageEngine.md) in order to access the underlying Stream, otherwise it's going to buffer all the data in memory and only callback once it's done.

If you check `req.file` in your route handler, Multer would normally provide a Buffer under the `buffer` field, but it's no longer present as I don't pass anything along in the callback, so I'm reasonably confident this is streaming as expected.

Below is a working solution.

Note: `parse.single('image')` is passed into the route handler. This refers to the multi-part field name I used.

```js
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const stream = require('stream');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer')

const AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "superSecretAccessKey";
const BUCKET_NAME = "my-bucket";
const BUCKET_REGION = "us-east-1";

const s3 = new aws.S3({
    region: BUCKET_REGION,
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});

const uploadStream = key => {
    let streamPass = new stream.PassThrough();
    let params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: key,
        Body: streamPass
    };
    let streamPromise = s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('ERROR: uploadStream:', err);
        } else {
            console.log('INFO: uploadStream:', data);
        }
    }).promise();
    return {
        streamPass: streamPass,
        streamPromise: streamPromise
    };
};

class CustomStorage {
    _handleFile(req, file, cb) {
        let key = req.query.file_name;
        let { streamPass, streamPromise } = uploadStream(key);
        file.stream.pipe(streamPass)
        streamPromise.then(() => cb(null, {}))
    }
}

const storage = new CustomStorage();
const parse = multer({storage});

router.post('/upload', parse.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.status(200).send({ result: 'Success!' });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500).send({ result: 'Fail!' });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

#### Update: A Better Solution

The [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) based solution I provided above is a bit hacky. So I took a look under the hood to see [how it worked](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/lib/make-middleware.js). This solution just uses [Busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) to parse and stream the file. Multer is really just a wrapper for this with some disk I/O convenience functions.

```js
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const express = require('express');
const Busboy = require('busboy');
const router = express.Router();

const AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "superSecretAccessKey";
const BUCKET_NAME = "my-bucket";
const BUCKET_REGION = "us-east-1";

const s3 = new aws.S3({
    region: BUCKET_REGION,
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});

function multipart(request){
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const headers = request.headers;
        const busboy = new Busboy({ headers });
        // you may need to add cleanup logic using 'busboy.on' events
        busboy.on('error', err => reject(err))
        busboy.on('file', function (fieldName, fileStream, fileName, encoding, mimeType) {
            const params = {
                Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
                Key: fileName,
                Body: fileStream
            };
            s3.upload(params).promise().then(() => resolve());
        })
        request.pipe(busboy)
    })
}

router.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await multipart(req)
        res.status(200).send({ result: 'Success!' });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500).send({ result: 'Fail!' });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Better solution doesn't work with AWS now, it return error :"header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented". Maybe some header data is missed when resolving by Busboy ??

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, Postman is behaving as it should — the "text-injection" is actually a web standard, used to identify/demarcate files on upload. Please see this [MDN Web Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) as well as [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) for why.

It's actually injecting that part regardless of the file type:

```
let streamPass = new stream.PassThrough();
// adding this
const chunks = [];
streamPass.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk) );
streamPass.on("end", () => {
    body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString();
    console.log(chunks, chunks.length)
    console.log("finished", body);  // <-- see it here
});
```

I tried several methods to control/change this, with no luck on a simple method — from the Postman end, I don't think this is a setting that *can* be changed, and from the NodeJS end...I mean it's *possible*, but the solution will most likely be clunky/complicated, which I suspect you don't want. (I could be wrong though...)

Given the above, I'll join @relief.melone in recommending `multer` as a simple solution.

If you'd like to use `multer` with `streams`, try this: (I've indicated where I made changes to your code):

```
// const uploadStream = (key) => {
const uploadStream = (key, mime_type) => {      // <- adding the mimetype

    let streamPass = new stream.PassThrough();
    
    let params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: key,
        Body: streamPass,
        ACL: 'public-read', // <- you can remove this
        ContentType: mime_type  // <- adding the mimetype
    };
    let streamPromise = s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("ERROR: uploadStream:", err);
        } else {
            console.log("INFO: uploadStream:", data);
        }
    }).promise();
    
    return {
        streamPass: streamPass,
        streamPromise: streamPromise
    };
};

// router.post("/upload", async (req, res) => {
router.post("/upload", multer().single('file'), async (req, res) => {      // <- we're adding multer
    try {
        
        let key = req.query.file_name;
        // === change starts here 

            // console.log(req.file); // <- if you want to see, uncomment this file

            let { streamPass, streamPromise } = uploadStream(key, req.file.mimetype);   // adding the mimetype

            var bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();

            bufferStream.end(req.file.buffer);

            bufferStream.pipe(streamPass); // no longer req.pipe(streamPass);

        // === change ends here 
        await streamPromise;
        
        res.status(200).send({ result: "Success!" });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500).send({ result: "Fail!" });
    }
});
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! This worked perfectly for me, however I'm still a little concerned that this isn't fully streaming. As Richard Dunn noted above - wouldn't a custom handler be required in order to actually stream the data?

Comment: Glad it worked . I'm on the fence on custom handler (as an aside, I also found this article where someone used a similar setup, but to stream to Google Cloud: https://medium.com/better-programming/streaming-images-videos-to-google-cloud-storage-with-node-js-express-and-multer-%EF%B8%8F-7455c60f310 ) But @Richard Dunn may be right. Since `Multer` is now looking good for you, I'd recommend reading the `Multer` repo (it's well explained) and further testing to see which works for you.